# How to detect most of uncommon hyperlinks and implicit redirects in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, c++, html, qt, web-crawler

I create website crawler in C++/Qt4.8.5 for Windows. I've found that sometimes the page could contain implicit(pseudo) redirect like `location.replace("some site");` in a `script` tag. And the result code of the request is 200 instead of something like `Permanently Removed`. I don't use  regular expressions for finding links to other pages, because it is not robust. I check attributes of HTML nodes instead of it. Primitive crawlers detect only `href` attribute in `a` tag. But there are other nodes which can contain urls. For example, `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0; URL=/relative_url">`. Where is unofficial list of tags/attributes (including `script`) which are relevant to url containers, implicit redirects? Maybe, some library in C++/Java contains handling of these cases.

Also, I've noticed that adding header of the preferred language to the request could not change page language for the site. I mean that Chrome has got page in some language, but my crawler has got page in another, default language, though it tries to mimic Chrome User Agent and language preferences. I've noticed that cookies in Chrome contained language property for that site. Are there any additional properties which can help server to generate page in the desired language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any additional properties which can help server to generate page in the desired language?

There would be several more possibilities, for example geo location (identified by IP, geolocation API, ...).